# Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser- Django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I tried to change password without the traditional way. Give old password and new password, update the old password. I used UpdateApiView.But i get the following error.

```
Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser
```

I tried passigng **Authorization** token in header using POST MAN. But Same error.

view.py

```
class ChangePassword(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ChangePasswordSerializer
    model = models.Customer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = self.request.user
        return obj

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
                return Response({"old_password": ["Wrong password."]}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            self.object.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
            self.object.save()
            return Response("Success.", status=HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):


    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

urls.py

```
 path('update_password', views.ChangePassword.as_view()),
```

**EDIT:**
I added TokenAuthentication in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

In views.py, i added
**authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )**

Now i got `name 'TokenAuthentication' is not defined`

I imported TokenAuthentication in views.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
```

But `Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the attribute `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )` to ChangePassword view.

Comment: {
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Comment: i passed old_password, new_password as form data. I used Braerer token as "Token 3c06246990ea0431229872ece5d5935b107518a2432"

Comment: I updated my post with what i have tried from your suggestion

Comment: Make sure that you have followed the following steps
1. Add the app `rest_framework.authtoken` in INSTALLED_APPS (in settings.py file)

2. Make sure you have added this in settings.py file
```REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ],
}```

Comment: I got name 'TokenAuthentication' is not defined. Is there anything to import in views.py